# In OpenID, is there a concept like SAMLSSO RelayState?

Tags: openid

I want to send a state with an OpenID request and get it back unchanged with the OpenID Provider (OP) response. SAMLSSO uses 'RelayState' parameter for this purpose. Is there such a way in OpenID?

I checked in the [specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) and seems if I append a parameter like RelayState to the 'openid.return_to' and send the request, OP should send it back in the response's  'openid.return_to' parameter.

But the Spec also mentions:

> The return_to URL MAY be used as a mechanism for the Relying Party to attach context about the authentication request to the authentication response. **This document does not define a mechanism by which the RP can ensure that query parameters are not modified by outside parties**; such a mechanism can be defined by the RP itself.

In SAMLSSO it is guaranteed that the same value sent in the RelayState will be sent back by the IdP. But with the above statement in the OpenID spec, I'm not sure using 'openid.return_to' is the proper way to achieve this. Is there a any other (better) way? Or have I misunderstood that statement in any way?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I have seen, openid.return_to is the only way to pass RelayState into the OpenID request. As the spec you smartly cited states:

- *"The return_to URL MAY be used as a mechanism for the Relying Party to attach context about the authentication request to the authentication response."* That is, this URL can take relay state into account through GET parameters just like SAMLSSO uses, such as `?RelayState=%2Fpost-login-page`.
- *"This document does not define a mechanism by which the RP can ensure that query parameters are not modified by outside parties; such a mechanism can be defined by the RP itself."* That is, this endpoint should also validate the request itself, just as SAML does through SHA fingerprints, etc.
- So in the end you can have a return_to URL that evaluates the outcome of OpenID verification, with or without RelayState, such as `/base?RelayState=` or just `/base`.

You've asked this question a while ago so please let us know if you've found a better option. But for now I am just confirming the assumption in your original post openid.return_to is the only way to take into account something like a RelayState. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong!